# Nginx Not Respecting File Permissions

Tags: nginx, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to apply permissions of `600` to certain files on my web server, but they are still accessible to the world (I can access them by navigating to direct link in browser e.g. `domain.com/test.txt`)!

The owner of these files is `www-data:www-data`. Even when I set permissions to `000`, the files are still accessible to the world (akin to permissions `777`)!

The only way I can make files inaccessible to the world is to apply `chown root:root` these files, but then `www-data` can't access them!

How can I make Nginx respect file permissions?

I'm using Nginx 1.8.1 and PHP 5.6.17.

Comment: Why do you say they are "accessible to the world"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I can access them in the browser.

Comment: If they are owned by www-data, then that is normal! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As a general rule, don't rely on UNIX permissions for security of files inside the wwwroot. Just don't put anything in the wwwroot that should be kept hidden!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, there are two situations. 1) I have a file, `log.txt` that records the number of visitors via `file_put_contents` (called from `sript.php`)--I don't want someone to be able to access `log.txt` via the browser. 2) I have a different file, `cron.php`, which is run hourly via cron--I don't want someone to be able to access `cron.php` via the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx is respecting file permissions. Nginx is running as `www-data` and Linux is enforcing the file permissions.  The issue here is two goals that conflict. Expectations need to be changed.

1. First, you want the files to "inaccessible to the world" via the web browser. This implies that they can't be readable and accessible by the `www-data` user.
2. Second, you observe that "www-data can't access them!" This conflicts with the first goal.

Comment: I did not know that (I'm more use to Apache). There are two situations. 1) I have a file, `log.txt` that records the number of visitors via `file_put_contents` (called from `script.php`)--I don't want someone to be able to access `log.txt` via the browser. 2) I have a different file, `cron.php`, which is run hourly via cron--I don't want someone to be able to access `cron.php` via the browser.

Comment: @Pamela, Apache permissions work the same way. You can store `log.txt` outside the web root in a location the `www-data` user can access. Also store `cron.php` outside the web root...unless you are using a faux-cron solution like Wordpress that makes HTTP calls back to a Cron-PHP scripts. If that's the case, *do* store cron.php in the web root and configure Nginx to only allow calls to cron.php from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: How about files like `wp-config.php`? Anything special I need to do in order to protect this file and other such configuration files?

Comment: @Pamela check out the official security documentation for Wordpress, which has a section on securing wp-config.php: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php

Comment: Thanks, I never knew `wp-config.php` can be stored one directory level above the WordPress installation. I'll go ahead and store my files outside the web root.